# Angular 8 Unit test EventSource using Jasmin

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have using EventSource in my application and written wrapper service like below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EventSourcePolyfill } from 'event-source-polyfill';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppConstants } from 'src/app/framework/constants/app.constants';

const base_url = `${AppConstants.REST_API_URL}datacontrolmanagment/notification`;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SseService {

  private eventSource;
  constructor() { }


  /**
   * 
   * @param url for Event Source Endpoint
   * @param headers passing authorization token
   */
  private getEventSource(headers) {
    return new EventSourcePolyfill(base_url, headers)
  }

  public getServerSentEvents(headers) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (!(this.eventSource instanceof EventSourcePolyfill)) {
        this.eventSource = this.getEventSource(headers);
      }

      this.eventSource.onmessage = msg => {
        console.log(msg)
        observer.next(msg);
      };

      this.eventSource.onerror = msg => {

      }; 

    });

  };

  public closeEventSource() {
    if ((this.eventSource instanceof EventSourcePolyfill)) {
      this.eventSource.close();
    }
  }
}
```

I have consume this service in one of my component.

I want to test this service for sake of code coverage.
However I am not able to figure it out how to test above code.

I tried to create mock/ dummy class of EventSource but no luck

Note: I have already tested the component code for this service.

Answer (score 0):

Because currently `EventSourcePolyfill` is an internal part of `SseService` you shouldn't mock it at all. You could mock it if it were a dependency passed by constructor for example.

You have 2 options here - create a factory token than provides `EventSourcePolyfill`, then you can mock it.

Or simply cover that `getServerSentEvents` emits as `EventSourcePolyfill` does.
Might you share its code in the question?

For the first case you can do next (it's an example, not a working copy)

```js
const base_url = `${AppConstants.REST_API_URL}datacontrolmanagment/notification`;

export const ESP = new InjectionToken<(headers: any) => EventSourcePolyfill>('ESP', {
    factory: () => headers => new EventSourcePolyfill(base_url, headers),
});
```

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SseService {

  private eventSource;
  constructor(@Inject(ESP) private eventSourceFactory: (headers: any) => EventSourcePolyfill) {}

  public getServerSentEvents(headers) {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (!(this.eventSource instanceof EventSourcePolyfill)) {
        this.eventSource = this.eventSourceFactory(headers);
      }

      this.eventSource.onmessage = msg => {
        console.log(msg)
        observer.next(msg);
      };

      this.eventSource.onerror = msg => {

      }; 

    });

  };

  public closeEventSource() {
    if ((this.eventSource instanceof EventSourcePolyfill)) {
      this.eventSource.close();
    }
  }
}
```

now you can mock it like that

```
it('', done => {
  const mockESP: any = jasmine.createSpyObj('EventSourcePolyfill', ['onmessage', 'onerror', 'close']);

  const mockFactory: any = jasmine.createSpy('EventSourceFactory');
  mockFactory.and.returnValue(mockESP);

  const service = new SseService(mockFactory);
  service.getServerSentEvents({myHeaders: true}).subscribe(result => {
    expect(result).toBe('test');
    done();
  });
  mockESP.onmessage.calls.argsFor(0)[0]('test');
  expect(mockESP).toHaveBeenCalledWith({myHeaders: true});
}
```

Comment: EventSourcePolyfill is just 3rd party npm package over EventSource defined in MDN to pass custom header.

Comment: aha, I see, then definitely try to add `ESP` token with a factory, that will allow to mock it.

Comment: will give it a try

Comment: I am also stuck in the same situation, did the solution worked?